# Wrong results in JavaScript table

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix for 12-tone music. The numbers between 0-11 show the intervals between pitches.

My script shows the matrix correctly as it runs initially with the page; but when we do another calculation with the button, it goes messy, even with the same pitch set.

Here is my script:

```
var exist = 0;

function execute (form) {
    therow = form.inputbox.value.split(",");
    matrix();
}


function shufflerow (form) {

    shuffle = function(v){  
        for (var y, x, z = v.length; z; y = parseInt(Math.random() * z), x = v[--z], v[z] = v[y], v[y] = x);
        return v;
    }

    var randomrow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

    shuffle(randomrow);
    var newLength = randomrow.unshift(0);
    form.inputbox.value = randomrow;
}


function matrix() {


    if (exist > 0) {
        var box = document.getElementById('matrixarea');
        var table = document.getElementById('matrixbox');
        box.removeChild(table);
    }


    if (typeof(therow) == 'undefined') {
        therow = new Array (0,3,2,1,9,5,7,6,8,4,11,10);
    }


    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    for(h=0 ; h < 12 ; ++h) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(therow[h]);
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    rows = new Array(11);

    for (i=1 ; i < 12 ; ++i) {
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        col = new Array(11);
        col[i] = 12 - therow[i];

        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(col[i]);
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        tblBody.appendChild(row);

        rows[i] = new Array(11);

        for (j=1 ; j < 12 ; ++j) {
            rows[i][j] = (col[i] + therow[j]) % 12;

            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            var cellText = document.createTextNode(rows[i][j]);
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }

    tblBody.appendChild(row);
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    body.appendChild(tbl);

    tbl.setAttribute('id','matrixbox');
    tbl.setAttribute("cellpadding", "5");
    tbl.setAttribute("cellspacing", "0");

    document.getElementById('matrixarea').appendChild(tbl);

    exist++;

}
```

Here is the form:

```
<div id="matrixarea">

    <form name="primerow" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="inputbox" value="">
        <input type="button" name="button2" value="Shuffle" onClick="shufflerow(this.form)">
        <input type="button" name="button1" value="Make" onClick="execute(this.form)">
    </form>

</div>
```

You can see it in action @ http://abbasmacioglu.home.anadolu.edu.tr/m.html.

In a correct matrix, the first number should be seen diagonally on the table, from the top left cell to the bottom right.

I'd be grateful for any help or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> therow = new Array (0,3,2,1,9,5,7,6,8,4,11,10)

That's an array of Number.

> therow = form.inputbox.value.split(",");

That's an array of String.

You then attempt to do arithmetic on the strings. '2'+'3'='23' not '5', so you get unexpected results.

```
for (var i= therow.length; i-->0;)
    therow[i]= +therow[i]; // convert to Number
```

Also matrix() seems much more complicated that it needs to be. How about:

```
function matrix(row) {
    var table= document.getElementById('matrixbox');
    if (table)
        table.parentNode.removeChild(table);
    table= document.createElement('table');
    table.id= 'matrixbox';

    for (var i= 0; i<row.length; i++) {
        var tr= table.insertRow(i);
        for (var j= 0; j<row.length; j++) {
            // this is the actual calculation here
            var value= (row[j]-row[i] +row.length)%row.length;
            tr.insertCell(j).appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('matrixarea').appendChild(table);
}
```

Then, to get rid of that nasty therow global, call using:

```
<body onload="matrix([0,3,2,1,9,5,7,6,8,4,11,10])">
```

and:

```
function execute(form) {
    var row= form.elements.inputbox.value.split(',');
    for (var i= row.length; i-->0;)
        row[i]= +row[i];
    matrix(row);
}
```

As a bonus, will work for any row length.

(Forget cellpadding/cellspacing; set ‘padding’ and ‘border-spacing’ through CSS instead. And don't use setAttribute() on HTML elements, as there are bugs in it on IE. And it's dead ugly).

Comment: That's it, thank you very much.

Btw, I couldn't run your matrix function, there's no table at all, do I miss something?

Thank you for other advises too, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Works for me, you just have to make sure to call it in your onload as above.

Comment: http://debuggable.com/posts/7+8===7-in-javascript:4acba016-d204-489b-b5a0-1fd0cbdd56cb

Comment: Luckily the unary `+` operator equates to `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt`; the former does not suffer from the Octal Problem.

Comment: Btw, there's another weird thing in my script. If the first number isn't zero, the results become wrong again. Fortunately it's not so important.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I renamed a variable wrongly, sorry — replace the ‘row=’ and subsequently ‘row.insertCell’ with ‘td’ instead (updated answer).

Comment: What are the results supposed to be for non-zero beginnings? Currently they're all relative to each other so naturally all results will be normalised to a zero first entry.

Comment: Your script is incredible, whew!! May I use it instead of mine :)
About non-zero beginnings, they supposed to be seen diagonally cross the table like zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for the string array, I don't know if there's a significant difference with bobince's way:

```
for (i=0; i<therow.length; i++) {
    therow[i] = parseInt(therow[i]);
}
```